# How to apply 'Column alignment' to an object array made of 'ClickToCopy'?

Tags: alignment, clicktocopy

There is the following code.

```
Column[{15!,  ClickToCopy[15!], Plot[x, {x, -1, 1}]}, Alignment -> Left]
```

I expect all the objects to be aligned to the left.
However, objects made with 'ClickToCopy' are not applicable.

[image]

What additional work will be needed?

Comment: `Column[{15!, Framed[ClickToCopy[15!]], Plot[x, {x, -1, 1}]}, 
 Alignment -> Left]`

Comment: Thanks to you, I solved the problem quickly.